# Prove that $\lim_{t\to0}(\log t)(1-(2t)^{t/2})=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, contest-math

Please prove that $(\log t)(1-(2t)^{t/2})$ tends to 0 as t tends to 0.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+t-%3E0+%281-%282t%29^%28t%2F2%29%29logt

It seems the limit converges to 0 pretty rapidly.

Answer (score 3):

Using the taylor series of the exponential function and the fact that $t\log t \to 0$,
$$(2t)^{t/2} = \exp\left(\frac{t}{2}\log (2t)\right) = 1 +\frac{t}{2}\log(2t) + o(t\log t) = 1 +\frac{t}{2}\log t + o(t\log t)
$$

Hence, as $t \to 0$.
$$
(\log t)(1-(2t)^{t/2})\;\sim -\frac{t}{2}(\log t)^2 \to 0
$$

Comment: I liked this one. Any other method I tried, say l'Hospital, yields nightmares. +1